# Why does my query fail when I don't wrap my table and columns with the ` character?

Tags: php, mysqli

Hopefully, some old sage can shed some light on this one. I'm baffled (easily).

When I prepare my SQL statement as such (using ` on the table and column names, which isn't shown on the output here?)...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order` (`orderid`, `username`, `payer_email`, `purchase_str`, `mc_gross`, `tnx_id`, `status`) VALUES (default,'$user','$useremail','$purchase_str','$mc_gross','46737264646','pending')";

$result = mysqli_query ( $cxn, $sql ) or die ( "Query died: fusername" );
```

...it successfully inserts a row.

However, when I use the no single quotes or ' on the table and column names, instead of ` it fails with a mysql error, i.e.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO order (orderid,username,payer_email,purchase_str,mc_gross,tnx_id,status) VALUES (default,'$user','$useremail','$purchase_str','$mc_gross','46737264646','pending')";

$result = mysqli_query ( $cxn, $sql ) or die ( "Query died: fusername" );
```

Error:

```
error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (orderid, username, payer_email, purchase_str, mc_gross, tnx_id, status) V' at line 1
```

OR

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'order' ('orderid', 'username', 'payer_email', 'purchase_str', 'mc_gross', 'tnx_id', 'status') VALUES (default,'$user','$useremail','$purchase_str','$mc_gross','','pending')";

$result = mysqli_query ( $cxn, $sql ) or die ( "Query died: fusername" );
```

Error:

```
error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''order' ('orderid', 'username', 'payer_email', 'purchase_str', 'mc_gross', 'tnx_' at line 1
```

I have another insert query without using ` or ' on table and column names that works fine, i.e.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username,password,created,email,firstname,lastname,dob,gender,house,street,area,city,county,postcode,country,skype,proofread) 
          VALUES ('$updatedb[username]','$hash',NOW(),'$updatedb[email]','$updatedb[firstname]','$updatedb[lastname]','$updatedb[dob]','$updatedb[gender]',
                  '$updatedb[house]','$updatedb[street]','$updatedb[area]','$updatedb[city]','$updatedb[county]','$updatedb[postcode]','$updatedb[country]',
                  '$updatedb[skype]','$updatedb[proofread]')";
```

Very, very confused. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Adios.

Comment: It's because `order` is a SQL Statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because <s>[`status`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html)</s> and [`order`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) is a reserved word in mysql and you need to escape it with backtick `` ` `` not with single quote `'`.

So your query will look:

```
INSERT INTO
`order` (
`orderid`, `username`, `payer_email`, `purchase_str`, `mc_gross`, `tnx_id`, `status`
)
VALUES (
default,'$user','$useremail','$purchase_str','$mc_gross','','pending'
)
```

You can find list of [*reserved words* here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

**Note:** It's a good practice to escape table and column names, because it's hard to memorize all reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

The word `order` and the word `status` are SQL statements, so you have to explicitly tell MySQL that it is the name of your table, not a command to MySQL. Read more on the `order` command [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)